# How can we control malicious calls to a web application with Nginx modsecurity module?

Tags: security, nginx, web-applications, mod-security, web-application-firewall

There is much commercial software(Akamai, Cloudflare, etc) to control the malicious calls/attacks (XSS, injection, DDOS, etc). Although, can we use ModSecurity with Nginx ? How to write custom rules in Lua to avoid major vulnerabilities for my web application. May i get some guidance on this? is there any opensource templates to follow?

Answer (score 1):

ModSecurity Core Rule Set *Developer on Duty* here. First of all, ModSecurity rules are written in "SecLang", a domain-specific language used to express ModSecurity rules and logic. It is also possible to write Lua scripts to provide extremely custom behaviour, but in practice this is *very* rarely necessary.

If you want to start with a great set of ModSecurity WAF rules to protect web applications, take a look at the Core Rule Set (CRS), which can be found at [coreruleset.org](https://coreruleset.org). CRS is the de facto set of free and open-source WAF/ModSecurity rules, and it's used by [some very big WAF vendors and service providers](https://coreruleset.org/docs/deployment/engine_integration_options/#existing-crs-integrations-cloud-and-cdn-offerings).

There are lots of great resources available to help get you started with Nginx + ModSecurity. I'll run few some of them here:

- Pre-made Docker images of Nginx + ModSecurity, as well as Apache + ModSecurity (https://github.com/coreruleset/modsecurity-docker)
- Pre-made Docker images of Nginx + ModSecurity + Core Rule Set (CRS), the de facto free and open-source WAF rule set (https://github.com/coreruleset/modsecurity-crs-docker)
- Christian Folini's tutorial series over at netnea on building your own Nginx + ModSecurity setup from scratch (https://www.netnea.com/cms/nginx-modsecurity-tutorials/)
- The ModSecurity (v3) Reference Manual (https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v3.x%29)
- The ModSecurity Handbook from Feisty Duck, which is worth every penny if you're going to be using ModSecurity for real world applications (https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/)
- The official Core Rule Set documentation, for CRS-specific information (https://coreruleset.org/docs/)